# Add a select based on a conditional to doctrine query builder

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-query

How can you add a select based on a conditional to the doctrine query builder?

I'd like to replicate SQL similar to this:

```
select p.id, p.id = 3 as first_result
from problem p
order by first_result desc, p.id
```

Comment: Do need a separate column in select part or you just need to order your results based on `p.id = 3`?

Comment: Don't need the separate select result - that's just how I did it in SQL

Answer (score 0):

As per docs you could use expression and mark this column as `HIDDEN` (not to include in results) but can be use in query like in your case to order results

DQL would look like

```
SELECT p, p.id = 3 AS HIDDEN first_result
FROM YourProblemEntity p 
ORDER BY first_result DESC, p.id
```

Or you can introduce `CASE` expression

```
SELECT p, 
CASE WHEN p.id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HIDDEN first_result
FROM YourProblemEntity p 
ORDER BY first_result DESC, p.id
```

[See DQL SELECT Examples](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)